# Cannot find module "framer-motion" - Nextjs 14

Tags: next.js, framer-motion

I wanted to use framer-motion for the first time today, I keep getting

> Cannot find module 'framer-motion'

I cannot wrap my head around it.
Framer-motion is there when I check my node_modules but I keep getting this error.

Edit: after creating a react app without using nextjs, it seems to work fine...

```
"dependencies": {
  "framer-motion": "^10.16.16",
  "next": "14.0.4",
  "react": "^18",
  "react-dom": "^18"
}
```